# Change class level variable Scope

Tags: c#

I have created some a int variable at class level, assigning value to it in constructor and decreasing the value of it in other method. This class can be called by multiple application at a time so there are possibilities that my variable value has changed by other application when one application is currently working on it.How to avoid this situation?

```
public class Database
{
    private int connectionRetries;


    private void SetRetryAndTimeouts(int seconds)
    {
        connectionRetries = 5;
    }

    private bool IsRetryRequired(Exception ex)
    {
        connectionRetries = --;
    }
}
```

Comment: usually every application that references/uses the class creates its own instance of the class. therefore every application hat its own 'class-internal counter'. nothing to do in this case.

Comment: As you said that multiple applications will use this class, so will they share one common instance of this class OR each of the applications will have their own instance of this class?

Comment: Each running instance of a program exists in what is called a "process space" or an "application domain" which has, among other things, its own protected region of memory. The memory is insulated from other applications (and vice versa) unless you go out of your way to make it available. Did you go out of your way to make it available? If you didn't, don't worry about that `int`.

Comment: First of all, your code is not valid C#, `connectionRetries = --`, what's that supposed to be?

Second of all, all of the members of this class are `private` so as far as we can see there's no way for any application to change anything about the state of an object of this class. Question unclear.